# How to restrict types which are allowed as "T" in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I've got a class `Foo<T>`. How can I say that I want `T` to be some class implementing `BarInterface`? Writing simply `class Foo<T implements BarInterface>` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `extends` instead of `implements`.

Comment: ... if I had a compiler at hand I could test it right away: shouldn't it be `class Foo<? extends BarInterface>` - `extends` is a [WildcardBound](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5.1) ...

Comment: +1 One note to add: Extends in the context of Generics has both the meaning of 'extends' AND 'implements', which I found quite confusing in the beginning.

Comment: @Andreas: no, it doesn’t work only on wildcards, it also works on template arguments.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I was really unsure, my first intention was that it `<T extends Something>` is correct but I was quite irritated after reading this one chapter of the language spec.