# How can I restrict Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
protected <T> T getValueForKey(String key) {

    T value = null;

    // currentStats is just a Bundle
    if (currentStats.containsKey(key)) {
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

How can I set restrictions? I.e. the T to be String or int or double for example. Is this possible?

P.S.

I don't want to use

```
protected <T extends String> T getValueForKey(String key) {

}
```

Because I don't want to have only Strings..

Comment: Note: `<T extends String> == <String>` because String is final.

Comment: protected <T> T getValueForKey(String key, Class<T> resultClass).. set the return type when calling getValue...

Comment: If you were restricting an input value, you could just use a couple different overloads, but there's no solution if you're restricting the output.

Comment: Why does it always return `value` which is `null`? Can you make the example more realistic?

Comment: @Alex You could use a class hierachy starting with BaseValue and extend IntValue, DoubleValue etc. from that and use <T extends BaseValue> as return type. But how do you decide which concrete  type to create from a ResourceBundle which only contains strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can't overload the return value I would suggest to have different accessor methods:

```
protected int     getIntForKey(String key);
protected double  getDoubleForKey(String key);
protected String  getStringForKey(String key);
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a way to restrict a generic type to only String, Integer and Double, but you could use `<T extends Comparable>` As String, Integer and Double all implement Comparable.
But many other class's also implement Comparable like java.util.Date,

Comment: That will also allow many other types (Date for example). I don't think this is what is being asked.

Comment: @assylias true, but do you think is there any other approach rather than this using generics ??

Comment: no I don't think there is, which would be a more appropriate answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected <T extends Object> T getValueForKey(String key);
```

I don't know of anyway you can return "A String or an Integer or a Double" etc.

You could always add some logic to check the class name of the object returned and throw an exception if the object returned is not one of your desired types.

Comment: Isn't the danger of this approach that you lose type safety?

Comment: Updated to use T extends Object

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this.
The classes used for type `T`  have to have something in common to be restricted, I.E. the classes that are `T` all have to implement some interface - assume this is `InterfaceName`

If class ClassName is the class that contains `protected  T getValueForKey(String key)`, you then have to declare the class `ClassName` as follows:

```
class ClassName<T extends InterfaceName>
```

A very similar question was already asked at this URL:

[How to restrict types which are allowed as "T" in a generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288053/how-to-restrict-types-which-are-allowed-as-t-in-a-generic-class)

Comment: To have a restriction the T types all have to have implement some interface in common - is there some kind of interface that they all implement?  (You can even require that the T implements multiple interfaces by using a comma separated list)

Answer (score 0):

Echoing comment of @anfy2002us -- If it's OK for the caller to know the desired type of the value associated with the given key, how about this?

```
protected <T> T getValueForKey(String key, Class<T> type) {
    return currentStats.containsKey(key) ? type.cast(currentStats.get(key)) : null;
}
```