# Generics with Inheritance

Tags: java, generics

The class `TrainingData` has an attribute `intent` which can be of any of the subtypes of class `Intent`. I am trying to use Java Generics to enforce that the generic type `T` can only be a sub-class of `Intent`. How can I do that?

```
public class TrainingData<T> extends Data {

    private T intent;
    private String id;

    public TrainingData (UserCommand userCommand, T intent) {
        super(userCommand);
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    public Klass getKlass() {
        return intent.getKlass(); // <-- THIS WORKS ONLY IF T extends from Intent
    }

    public Intent getIntent() {
        return intent;
    }

    public void setIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrainingData [intent=" + intent + ", id: " + id + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict types which are allowed as "T" in a generic class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288053/how-to-restrict-types-which-are-allowed-as-t-in-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The class TrainingData has an attribute intent which can be of any of the subtypes of class Intent.

Try with `T extends Intent` that means any class that extends Intent are accepted.

```
public class TrainingData<T extends Intent> extends Data {...}
```

Read more [Java Tutorial Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

---

Change it for getter & setter methods as well.

```
class TrainingData<T extends Intent> extends Data {

    private T intent;

    public T getIntent() {
        return intent;
    }

    public void setIntent(T intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's like this:

```
public class TrainingData<T extends Intent>
```

See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html for more info.